# Kendo ui webservice callback function

Tags: web-services, callback, grid, kendo-ui

Have been following examples of calling a web service (GET request), and changing it slightly pointing it to my own service. The issue is that kendo appends a callback to the request address in the form of

```
...?callback=jQuery1910806812594877556_1375342185702&_=1375342185703
```

the web service fails to respond with an invalid arguments error, the issue being the & (ampersand). If you remove it, the service returns a response.

Is it possible to change the callback format on the kendo side to exclude it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This _=1375342185703 is appended by jQuery.ajax which the Kendo DataSource uses under the hood. That thing is used as a cache buster (prevents browser caching). The fix is simple - disable jQuery caching:

```
transport: {
   read: {
      url: "your service",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      cache: true // enable caching which disables the cache buster
   }
}
```